# Python Flask getting 404 Not Found Error

Tags: python, http-status-code-404, flask

I am designing this simple website using Flask. But I am getting a 404 error for my hello method. Whenever I click on the button "rate artists," it's giving me the error, but templates for home.html, hello.html, and artist.html are all correct. I do not know what part of my code is wrong. Any help?

```
@app.route("/",methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    if request.method=="GET":
        return render_template("home.html")
    if request.method=="POST":
        if (request.form["button"]=="login"):
            return render_template("hello.html",name=request.form["name"])

@app.route("/hello",methods=['GET','POST'])
def hello():
    if request.method=="GET":
        if(request.form["button"]=="rate artists"):
            return render_template("artist.html")
```

Comment: just so you know, your `if` statements that look like `if(...):`, while they work, are really not generally accepted convention.  You should really have it be, for the penultimate line for example:
`if request.form['button'] == 'rate artists':`

Comment: Also, you need to give some more information for people to help.  Just saying that the "rate artists" button isn't working won't help if you don't give any information about the button.

Comment: Does "/hello?button=rate+artists" return a 404 error as well?

Answer (score 5):

I'm having the same problem.

I'm doing some experimental CORS tests between backbone and Flask as an endpoint in a different url

Are you using SERVER_NAME in your Config object or when you use the app.run ?

I put the SERVER_NAME but did not specify the port,

```
class Config(object):
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = True
    STATIC_FOLDER = STATIC_FOLDER
    STATIC_URL = STATIC_URL
    NAVIGATION_JS = '/static/js/navigation.js'
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    REDIS_HOST_SESSION = 'localhost'
    REDIS_PORT_SESSION = 6379
    REDIS_DB_SESSION = 2
    REDIS_HOST = 'localhost'
    REDIS_PORT = 6379
    REDIS_DB = 3
    SERVER_NAME = 'api.jvazquez.com.ar'
```

Server name doesn't has the port

I also was getting 404 for any of the routes I had defined (*if you are interested, I'm using blueprints*)

When I send a request to my flask app using curl, I was getting 404, here is the output
I was getting 404 for all of the blueprints that I had defined

```
jvazquez@aldebaran:~$ curl -i http://api.jvazquez.com.ar:5000/alive/
HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 233   
Set-Cookie: session=94c2c120-34c0-4a00-b094-7b5623d438ff; Domain=.api.jvazquez.com.ar; HttpOnly; Path=/
Server: Werkzeug/0.9.4 Python/2.7.3
Date: Wed, 25 Dec 2013 11:21:16 GMT
```

So, check if you have defined the config variable SERVER_NAME and it has the port

Answer (score 3):

For whatever reason I encountered this when I set the SERVER_NAME to `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.  I don't know why that was important with my setup, but after changing it to `localhost` everything started working again.