# All Flask Endpoints return 404 (Not Found)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have an API with 12 endpoints which was working fine, then the endpoints started failing and now all return 404 status code. Here are some of my files
My **run.py**

```
import os

from app import create_app

config = os.getenv('APP_SETTINGS')
app = create_app(config)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I register my endpoints in **app.py** like so

```
 from flask import Flask
 from .api.v2.views.userview import auth


 def create_app(config):
 '''Creates all Flask configurations and returns app.
    Expects config name'''
     app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
     app.config['JSON_SORT_KEYS'] = False
     app.config.from_object(app_config[config])
     app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)

     app.url_map.strict_slashes = False
     app.register_blueprint(auth)
     return app
```

And finally my endpoint **user.py**

```
     from flask import request, jsonify
     from flask import Blueprint

     from ..models.usermodel import UserModel

     usr_obj = UserModel()
     auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__, '/api/v2')


     @auth.route('/auth/signup', methods=['POST'])
     def user_signup():
         fullname = request.json['fullname']
         username = request.json['username']
         email = request.json['email']
         password = request.json['password']

         data = usr_obj.inituser(fullname, username, email, password)
         return jsonify(data), 201
```

When I try to run this endpoint or any other in Version 1 (/api/v1) I get a Not Found error. I have also tried [THIS SOLUTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537996/python-flask-getting-404-not-found-error) with no success.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a silly mistake the Blueprint declaration ought to be

```
 auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__, url_prefix='/api/v2')
```